# Security of a sessionID stored in a div in the page source

Tags: web-application, session-management

I've just come across a web application that appears to *store* my current `sessionID` in form of a `div` element, which is not displayed on the web page.

This is an odd method, but to be honest I don't see an actual security risk there. Am I missing something? Can this method be considered as secure? I understand that properly configured cookies are preferable as they increase the effort to steal the sessionID via XSS.

Comment: Have you checked the cookies? I believe its not uncommon for ASP.NET applications to include the sessionId in a div but that a cookie is used to actually maintain the session.

Comment: I did check the cookies. No cookies set, nothing in the local storage either. Some JS included in the web-page appends the sessionID in requests, from what I can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the session is stored in a variable on the page or within a cookie they suffer the same risks. That said storing a sessionID on the page is a method that has been used many times. To mitigate any risks with sessionIDs being tampered with you can always ensure they are transported over the TLS protocol.

Comment: They do not share all the same risks, as Dolores mentioned in the question. A cookie can be marked HttpOnly so XSS can't compromise it, a div on the page cannot have the same protection.